# Full Width Layout is not saved in admin

Tags: magento2

**`admin -> Categories -> mycategory -> Display Settings`**

When I Full Width **Layout -> Yes** and Save the problem is not saved.

Can you help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Field "Full-Width Layout"  is not Magento 2 default category attribute

and **This type of feature does not exist at magento2 default**.

> May it coming from Any extension or your theme as this is not default
>   Magento 2 feature.

**So, you should contact your receptive extension provider or theme provider**.

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 does not come from full width layout
I think this is your Module layout that you have used in category page in admin
You should check Module layout .

Comment: Ok if you want more help then tell me